# PJSIP server development

Tags: macos, window, pjsip

When using pjsip technology to develop a server, the official web site is a bit difficult to use when looking for a way to develop a server.

It has an introduction on how to develop a client application with the library, but not how to implement a server.

Any one direct me to some reference documentation or blob posts or other web site that can help show me how to create a pjsip based server?

Answer (score 7):

You can find a sample SIP proxy implementation inside the PJSIP source code: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/stateful_proxy.c and http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/stateless_proxy.c

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk SCF module uses pjsip. Maybe that will shed some light

More information, visit
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/TOP/How+to+add+a+PJSIP+module+to+Asterisk+SCF
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Stack+Research

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. [PJSUA utility in pjproject](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/tree/master/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua) tree acts as SIP server, [Zoiper Softphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app&hl=en&gl=US) successfully connects and makes calls.